# ios - why do some of my screens have a navigation controller and some do not

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

Below is a storyboard of my app. For some reason, some of the screens have a navigation bar on top, and some do not. How can I add the navigation bar to each of the screens? Any thoughts on  what I did incorrectly for this to happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the `Simulated Metrics` (under Attributes Inspector) of your `ViewControllers`?

Comment: @ohr yeah it says inferred for all the options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple gotchas here to be aware of:

- The `Simulated Metrics`, as mentioned by @ohr, are just there for convenience when laying out your views.  This lets you account for potentially having the 44px navigation bar in place, so you know to layout your UI elements on your view accordingly.  This does *not* mean you have a navigation controller (or navigation bar) actually within the view.
- To have a functional navigation bar, you have a couple options:

1) In your Storyboard, embed your `UIViewController` within a `UINavigationController`.  This can be done by clicking *Editor* in the Menu, then *Embed in* -> *Navigation Controller*.  Make sure you have your desired view controller in the storyboard selected.

2) If you just need a one-off navigation bar (say you are displaying a modal and don't need to push views onto the view hierarchy), then you have the option of just dropping a `UINavigationBar` into your storyboard view controller.  You'll just need to wire up the buttons to IBActions to have them perform the desired task.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, I just tried to embed the UIViewController in the NavigationController, and a navigationcontroller showed up on the screen...but I already have one like that pointing to the starting point of my app....so it felt like that wasn't right.

Comment: Btw I have a UINavigationController in my app that is already inside the UITabBar - maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: It's okay to have many navigation controllers throughout your storyboard.  However, if you are just pushing view controllers onto the same view stack, you **wont** need another navigation controller.  Use a `segue` instead, and just use the `Simulated Metrics` to show the nav bar in the child view controller so you can layout your view appropriately.  Please accept the answer if you got what you were looking for!

Comment: hmmm...not working...adding a nav bar is also having a side-effect of making the screen appear wider on the storyboard...kind of strange.

Comment: Making the screen wider?  Not sure why that would be the case, unless your doing something with landscape.

It sounds like you DONT need another nav bar, or even another navigation controller...just add a *push* `segue` and simulate the nav bar in your child view controller.

Comment: And there are many other screens which always have the inferred everywhere on the simulated-metrics, and do show the navigation bar...very strange. :)

Comment: Seems to be working to just re-do the push segue...I was already doing the push segues, but maybe something was wrong before that I was not aware of..lets cross our fingers here :)

Comment: ah ok I got the error: nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2012-08-16 12:51:34.096 BusinessPlan[20843:f803] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2012-08-16 12:51:34.097 BusinessPlan[20843:f803] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ForgotPasswordController: 0x68f7ad0>.

Comment: Oh figured it out..it was some left-over code that was doing a seguey inside a seguey -- DOH :)